# Robust laptop with SSD

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for a laptop with an SSD that is pretty much focused on the essentials, which means I don't care if it comes with a good webcam, or if it has fingertip reader or touchscreen or any of that.

What I would like it to have is

```
SSD instead of HD
a decent amount of ram (at least 6GB)
weight less than 2 kg (4.4 lb)
at least a core i5 in terms of processing
```

I'm asking this here because, although I can find specs like the ones above in laptops like Samsung NP900, they always seem to have some of the things that I listed as unnecessary (NP900 for example has touchscreen), and I'd like to avoid "wasting" money on those features.

I'm not really working with a price limit because it really depends on the specs. If I buy a laptop that comes with a 164 GB SSD I'll be willing to pay less than I would for a 256 GB one and so on. Although it would be nice to keep it under $900 or so, if possible.

Also, I'm going to use for Linux. So companies like [system 76](https://system76.com/) are acceptable.

Cheers

Comment: I recommend that you find a laptop with a chassis and CPU that you like for a nice price, then just upgrade the SSD and RAM on your own.  You'll likely save money, and not be limited by factory available models.  Sell the removed guts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting the results of my own investigation here since none of the previous answers quite did the trick (either because of weight or price).

The laptop that comes closest to the solution for me is [this Asus Zenbook](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6R454D0638&cm_re=asus_zenbook-_-9SIA6R454D0638-_-Product), which weights only 1.45 kg and has a 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7-6500U Dual-Core with 8GB RAM.

Granted it's not the most powerful laptop listed here, but it has still good specs and the and low voltage processor that should increases my battery life.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to recommend either of these two laptops. Neither of them focus on having a touchscreen display, fingerprint reader, HD webcam, or other "gimmick".

---

At a little over $610, the [**Lenovo IdeaPad 510s**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LNOECBE) best fills your requirements.

Here's a rundown of the system:

- i7-7500U (2.7GHz)
- AMD Radeon R7 M460 GPU
- 14" Non-Touchscreen 1920x1080 Display
- 8GB RAM
- 256GB SSD
- 3.7lbs (~1.7kg)

---

For about $900, the [**Lenovo IdeaPad 310**](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAA0S57P3049) has more RAM and a larger SSD, at the cost of some weight, GPU performance, and screen resolution.

Here's a rundown of the system:

- i7-7500U (2.7GHz)
- Integrated Intel HD Graphics 620
- 15.6" Non-Touchscreen 1366x768 Display
- 12GB RAM
- 512GB SSD
- 4.85lbs (~2.2kg)

Comment: The first one would be perfect, if radeon graphics weren't something to *really* avoid for us, linux users.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found quite a few that meet your requirements, [This Acer Aspire Stands out to me.](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834315672&cm_re=laptop-_-34-315-672-_-Product)

It seems to meet all your requirements, I filtered my search by SSD, 6th or 7th gen i5/i7 and either 8 or 16gb of ram.

This laptop comes with

- Intel Core i5 7th Gen 7200U (2.50 GHz)
- 8 GB DDR4 Memory
- 256 GB SSD
- NVIDIA GeForce 940MX
- 1920 x 1080 display
- Windows 10 Home 64-Bit

It doesn't have any crazy features like eyeball scanners or anything.

If this one does not fit the bill, here is a list of all of my search results on newegg, [Link.](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=laptop&ignorear=0&N=100006740%20600004804%20600136700%20600423158%20600423159%204814%20601283907%20601283906%20600003982%20601283905%20601283909%20600003988&isNodeId=1)

I hope this helps!